# what is the disadvantage of blended wing body ,that they not used to achieve more than subsonic speed?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-performance, military

Blended wings have more efficiency than today's wing design,high lift to drag ratio,more efficiency,less fuel rate ,it have lot of advantages so why not they used for commercial airplanes as well as military aircraft rather than UAV.

Comment: NO its not i have a different thought?

Comment: Now that you have changed the title, you should probably explain what exactly you mean in the detailed text of the question.

Comment: What of your question does the accepted answer of the proposed duplicate not answer?

Comment: The already question is asked about why not blended wing passenger airplane in operation? i am not suppose to ask  that type,why they not achieve more than subsonic speeds as it have more L/D ratio than today's wing design and what is disadvantages not to acheive supersonic speeds.

Comment: @ThangarajSundaramoorthy: But the answer on that question explains that blended-wing-body designs do _not_ have more efficiency that today's wing designs, making the rest of the question pointless.

Answer (score 0):

One of the few production designs that approaches a blended-wing-body was [Lockheed Sr-71](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_SR-71_Blackbird):

[image: Sr-71]]

Surprise, with maximum Mach 3.2 it is also the fastest production aircraft ever built.

Because blended-wing-body does *not* have better L/D at low speed. But generating part of lift with the body has some advantage for high-speed aircraft as it allows smaller wings that is better for high speed (and worse for low-speed).